# CoAP protocol implementation

Tags: client, coap

How to make a generic code for multiple feeds or connected devices to a CoAP client, such that we can control them via the same function with the incoming parameters.

Like in the GET method of CoAP it sends Get-feedname/device name, where we can receive the message and send accordingly.

Comment: You question is not quite clear. Can you add some more details on what you want to do.

Comment: the Question was to add multiple URI under the same title in CoAP.  example - **coap.server(callback_light, "Coap/Arun");
coap.server(callback_light, "Coap/Hari");** . Dynamically in a single line. (say Looping method of String array). I used STRCAT but the array elements are added continuosly one after the other.

Comment: Could you be more specific ???

Comment: The question was regarding the concatenation of the name COAP with multiple other names inside a loop. It was resulting in COAP/x, COAP/xy, COAP/xyz. But we have made a workaround and implemented our needed logic. Thanks for the response.